# How to customise select tag in Grails

Tags: select, grails, plugins, field, relation

I have this `hasMany` relation, between a client and a product. When I generate the views and controllers, in the create view of the product I can chose a client. By default Grails displays a select containing only the id of the clients. How can I change that? For example I want to show only the name of the client instead of the id.

I'm using Grails 3.3, Here is the domain code:

**client.groovy**:

```
class client {
    String FirstName
    String LastName

    static hasMany = [products: Product]
}
```

**product.groovy**:

```
class product {
    String Name
    int Price
    Client c

    static belongsTo = Client
}
```

Comment: you want to stick with default scaffolding templates, or you want to touch each view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize how the `select` looks like by specifying `optionKey` and `optionValue` attributes:

```
<g:select from="${Client.list()}" name="client" optionKey="FirstName" optionValue="id" />
```

See [the ref doc](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.0/ref/Tags/select.html) for details.

If you need to do something fancier, like show first AND last name, then you could pre-process the list a bit:

```
<g:select from="${Client.list().collect{ [ id:it.id, name:it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName ] }}" name="client" optionKey="name" optionValue="id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the default generated select list will use the `toString()` method of the object as the display value for each `<option>` and the id for the key value.  The easiest way to change the default display would be to override `toString()` in your product class:

```
@Override
String toString() {
  name
}
```